# Export informations from tons of web pages

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, urllib

I have a python 3 script that using libraries urllib.request and BeautifulSoup load content of an website, and export informations from it to csv file or MySQL database.
Here are main lines of code from script:

```
# ... 

url = urllib.request.urlopen("<urls here>")
html = url.read()
url.close()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
# Create lists for html elements
nadpis = soup.find_all("span", class_="nadpis")     
# Some more soups here...

onpage = len(no) # No. of elements on page
for i in range(onpage):
    nadpis[i] = one_column(nadpis[i].string)
    # Some more soups here

if csv_export:
    with open("export/" + category[c][0] + ".csv", "ab") as csv_file:
        wr = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=';', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, lineterminator='\n') 
        wr.writerow("<informations from soup>")

# Insert to database
if db_insert:
    try:        
        cursor.execute("<informations from soup>")
        conn.commit()
    except Exception:
        print("Some MySQL error...")
        break

# ...
```

Full script has 200 lines of code so I will not spam it here. And everything just works. Problem is that I need to scan and export informations from tons of webpages (everything is in while loop, but that is not necessary right now) and its getting really slow (hours of running time).

Is there a faster way to do this?

I implemented multiprocessing, so I can utilize every CPU core but anyway it can take 24 hours to export everything. I even did a test run on Amazon EC2 server, but anyway it was not faster, so problem is not that I have a slow PC or internet connection.

Comment: there are many ways to improve performance but there is not enough information in your question. You should identify possible bottlenecks (remote server(s), bandwidth, latency,  cpus, disk, etc) and see whether you can achieve your performance goal

Answer (score 1):

If you are running into performance issues, I would recommend you start [profiling](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) your code. This will give you a pretty detailed idea about where your code spends most of its time running. You could also measure the time it takes for the script to scrap each web page, maybe you'll find out that some webpages take too more time to load than other, which would suggest you are not limited by your bandwidth but by the servers you are trying to access.

However, what do you call 'tons of webpages'? If your script is reasonably optimized and if you are using all you CPU cores, it looks like you might just have to many webpages to scrap in order to do it as fast as you want (btw, how fast would you want it to be ?)

Comment: Well, as fast as possible. I read about this tool called ZMap: http://pastebin.com/Ah2v2fiW Something that works like it would be just perfect, so I was wondering if there is not some library for it by now. By "tons of webpages" I mean like 200k of individual pages. I will look into profiling, thanks for tip.

Comment: ZMap looks like a tool to scan adresses, but doesn't seem to be fit for scrapping (but I might be wrong).
Also, I would recommend you separate the scraping process from the writing process (in a cvs or a database). Since you are using parallelization, you could use one specialized worker to output your results, which would free up some time for the other workers to scrap your content.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [`simple-requests`](http://pythonhosted.org/simple-requests/), something like:

```
from simple_requests import Requests

# Creates a session and thread pool
requests = Requests(concurrent=2, minSecondsBetweenRequests=0.15)

# Cookies are maintained in this instance of Requests, so subsequent requests
# will still be logged-in.
urls = [
    'http://www.url1.com/',
    'http://www.url2.com/',
    'http://www.url3.com/' ]

# Asynchronously send all the requests for profile pages
for url_response in requests.swarm(urls):
    html = url_response.html
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

    # Some more soups here...

    # Write out your file...
```